# C# Thread Static Variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, task

I have a static DataLibrary class that implements a singleton pattern.

```
        public static FacilityRepository FacilRepo
        {
            get
            {
                if (_facilRepo == null)
                {
                    _facilRepo = new FacilityRepository(Authenticated.UserId);
                    if (Authenticated.FacKey.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var fac in _facilRepo)
                            fac.IsSelected = (fac.FacilityKey == Authenticated.FacKey);                        
                    }
                }
                return _facilRepo;
            }
        }

private static FacilityRepository _facilRepo;
```

When I access this from different threads using Task.Factory.StartNew the FacilityReposity gets recreated multiple times how can I avoid this.

Comment: If you are creating many new threads at the same time and they are all trying to access the FacilRepo property.. it may be because there is no locking around the property. Take a look at http://en.csharp-online.net/Singleton_design_pattern%3A_Thread-safe_Singleton (right at the bottom)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you've actually got a thread-local variable here - you've just got a race condition because you're not implementing the singleton pattern properly.

I have a [page about the singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) which gives some better options. (In particular, as you're using the TPL you must be using .NET 4, so the `Lazy<T>` option is definitely a contender.)

Comment: excellent Article!!!! Thank you .  Ill accept your answer as soon as it lets me 4 more minutes.

Answer (score 2):

This Article by Jon Skeet might be helpful:
[Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

These questions might be helpful too:

- [Singleton by Jon Skeet clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550925/singleton-by-jon-skeet-clarification)
- [Singleton Pattern with Public Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431810/singleton-pattern-with-public-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if multiple threads access your property for the first time, before `_facilRepo` is initialised. You have to lock the initialisation code like this:

```
private static object _facilRepoLock = new object();
public static FacilityRepository FacilRepo
{
    get
    {
        if (_facilRepo == null)
        {
            lock (_facilRepoLock)
            {
                if (_facilRepo == null)
                {
                    _facilRepo = new FacilityRepository(Authenticated.UserId);
                    if (Authenticated.FacKey.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var fac in _facilRepo)
                            fac.IsSelected = (fac.FacilityKey == Authenticated.FacKey);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _facilRepo;
    }
}

private static FacilityRepository _facilRepo;
```

Comment: Without the variable being volatile, I'm not sure that's genuinely thread-safe. There are simpler ways of achieving thread-safety than using double-checked locking.

Comment: Ahh, interesting.. I didn't know that before.. Your article is an eye-opener :)